# Why doesn't appear text in d3 geomap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
    import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import * as d3 from "d3";

    import koreaMap from "../../imgs/map.json";

    const Map = props => {
      const mapRef = useRef(null);
      const mapContainer = props.mapContainer;

      console.log(koreaMap);
      useEffect(() => {
        const map = d3.select(mapRef.current);

        if (map && mapContainer) {
          const width = mapContainer.getBoundingClientRect().width;
          const height = mapContainer.getBoundingClientRect().height;
          const projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], koreaMap);
          const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

          const kopreaCapital = map
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(koreaMap.features)
            .enter()
            .append("g");

          kopreaCapital.append("path").attr("d", path);

          kopreaCapital.append("text").attr("fill", "black").text("hi");
        }
      }, [mapContainer]);

      return <svg ref={mapRef} />;
    };

    export default Map;
```

I have appended text element inside of  element. But it wasn't work.
I have question why text doesn't appear despite of using append("text") in d3
The text element is appear in the html in Chrome DevTools.